# How do I inspect the certificate chain and the self-signed certificate?

Tags: npm

From within my project

```
npm install @angular/compiler-cli@">=9.0.0 <10" --dry-run
npm WARN registry Unexpected warning for https://registry.npmjs.org/: Miscellaneous Warning SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN: request to https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular%2fcompiler-cli failed, reason: self signed certificate in certificate chain
npm WARN registry Using stale data from https://registry.npmjs.org/ due to a request error during revalidation.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@~2.1.2 (node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.1.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

npm ERR! code SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN
npm ERR! errno SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN
npm ERR! request to https://registry.npmjs.org/yargs-parser/-/yargs-parser-18.1.3.tgz failed, reason: self signed certificate in certificate chain

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\afeldstein01\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-09-01T16_10_33_062Z-debug.log
```

Yes, most of my post is (formatted as) code. That's because the entire question is contained in the Title. So I'm writing these unnecessary words so that StackOverflow allows me to post my question.

Answer (score 0):

run below command. set variable value. then try again

```sh
export NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS="/absolute/path/to/self-signed-certificate.crt"
```